# Regarding MS Access 2003 and VBA programming

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

My requirement is to add a blank table onto a Form in MS Access 2003 on which I can paste the data copied from the excel sheet. This table need to have the same column structure as excel sheet.

But I am unable to find any UI component which can do this task.

Jagu

Answer (score 0):

First step, you need to create a table with same columns data type in same order than excel

Then create a form for this table allowing datasheet view.

when you open this for in data sheet view, you can past records from excel. For this first copy excel records to clipboard and then right click on asterisk (*) in access form (datasheet view) and paste.